# React Native Animated with useNativeDriver - _reactNative.Animated.event(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use the native driver for dealing animation in React Native app.
I'm using `Animated.FlatList`, and I want to define `onScroll` outside the `render` function.
Here's the code snippet.

```js
class FlatListWithAnimation extends React.PureComponent {
  [...]

  onScroll = (event) => Animated.event(
    [{
      nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY },
      },
    }],
    {
      useNativeDriver: true,
      listener: (event, gestureState) => console.log(event, gestureState),
    },
  )(event);


  render() {
  [...]
    return (
      [...]
      <Animated.FlatList
        key="FlatList"
        data={placeHolderData}
        renderItem={this.renderPlaceHolder}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
      />
      [...]
    );
  }
}
```

However, this produce `_reactNative.Animated.event(...) is not a function` error. When I put `Animated.event` inside directly `onScroll={...}`, then it works. But I want to know how I can use `Animated.event` outside the `render` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: **it isn't possible**. You can use native driver only by passing `Animated.event` into `onScroll` handler.

`PanResponder` doesn't support native animations yet, because it's implemented in pure JS.

You can write it like this, but it will work like `useNativeDriver: false`

```
onScroll = (event) => Animated.event(
  [{
    nativeEvent: {
      contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY },
    },
  }],
  {
    useNativeDriver: true,
    listener: ({ nativeEvent }) => this.state.scrollY.setValue(nativeEvent.contentOffset.y),
  },
).__getHandler()(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** wrap Animated.event with function.

Change

```
onScroll = (event) => Animated.event({...}, { useNativeDriver: true })(event);
```

to

```
onScroll = Animated.event({...}, { useNativeDriver: true });
```

And for others, do not forget to pass this handler into `Animated.FlatList`/`Animated.ScrollView` (**not** just `FlatList`/`ScrollView`).